# Using Spring with Apache Flink - Command line arguments are not available to Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-flink, command-line-arguments

**Background**

I have a Spring Boot application which I am trying to run on an *[Apache Flink](https://flink.apache.org/)* cluster. This is a standard Spring Boot application with a `main` class annotated using `@SpringBootApplication` (Code snippet added later in this question).

When I tried launching my Spring Boot application on a standalone Apache Flink cluster using the following command, I immediately started facing issues with bean autowiring. Flink was unable to desearlize the beans that have been Autowired.

> ./bin/flink run
> examples/streaming/my-springboot-function.jar

On further research, I found that the flink functions are executed on `TaskExecutors` and when this happens, Flink would first seralize the function and then deserialize it on a `TaskExecutor`. At this point, the dependencies would come out as null and not automatically be autowired.

To solve this issue, I simply created my own custom Spring Context and called it in the `open` method of my function and the beans autowiring was triggered as expected.

But the current issue that I am facing now is that Spring Boot is unable to map the command line arguments to the `@Value` annotation marked fields.

**Code and details**

The custom Spring Context :

```
public class CustomSpringContext {

    private transient final ConcurrentHashMap<String, ApplicationContext> springContext;

    public CustomSpringContext() {
        springContext = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    public ApplicationContext getContext(String configurationPackageName) {
        return springContext.computeIfAbsent(configurationPackageName, AnnotationConfigApplicationContext::new);
    }

    public <T> T autowiredBean(T bean, String configurationPackageName) {
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = getContext(configurationPackageName);
        AutowireCapableBeanFactory factory = context.getAutowireCapableBeanFactory();
        factory.autowireBean(bean);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

The Flink function : **Notice the `open` method**

```
@Component
public class TransformFunction extends RichMapFunction<AuditRecord, String> implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private transient CacheDao cacheDao;

    @Autowired
    private transient ProcessController processController;

    public String map(AuditRecord auditRecord) throws Exception {

        //Some business logic
    }

    @Override
    public void open(Configuration parameters) throws Exception {
        super.open(parameters);
        //Autowire the dependent beans in this class 
        new CustomSpringContext().autowiredBean(this, "com.mypackage");
    }
}
```

This solved my first issue which was the autowiring of beans after the function is deserialized on the `TaskExecutor` of Flink.

But I am now running into an issue such that if I pass any command line arguments to my program, they are not being injected into the properties marked with `@Value`. In a typical Spring Boot application, properties marked as `@Value` can be populated via command line as well and not necessarily from the applicaiton.properites. But that doesn't seem to be the case here.

For example, I have the following configuration class in my application. It uses `@Value` :

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.mypackage")
public class TaskApplicationConfig {

    @Value("commandLineArgument");
    private String commandLineArgument;

    //other bean configurations etc

}
```

Spring is unable to find `commandLineArgument` at runtime even though I pass it as a program input. I get the following exception at run time :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 'commandLineArgument' in string value [${commandLineArgument}]

I did some digging and know why this happens. In a typical Spring Boot Application, we implement the `ApplicationRunner` interface in our main class and override the `run` method. This `run` method injects the command line arguments into the context which are then accessible via `@Value` annotations. Example :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TaskApplication implements ApplicationRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(TaskApplication .class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void run(ApplicationArguments args) throws Exception {
        //call some business logic
    }
}
```

But since the Flink function (`TransformFunction`) is creating a custom spring context, there is no application runner or a a callback run method. In turn, the fields marked as `@Value` are not being mapped with command line arguments.

How do I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue myself by annotating my function itself with `@SpringBootApplication`. This way, when the funciton runs in a Flink `TaskExecutor`, the `TaskExecutor` would end up reloading all the beans and autowiring them.

Code changes that I made :

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class TransformFunction extends RichMapFunction<AuditRecord, String> implements Serializable {

    @Autowired
    private transient CacheDao cacheDao;

    @Autowired
    private transient ProcessController processController;

    public String map(AuditRecord auditRecord) throws Exception {

        //Some business logic
    }
    
}
```

With this change, I no longer needed the `CustomSpringContext` class and no longer needed to load the beans manually in the `open` method of the`TransformFunction`

The Apache Flink pipeline would then be created as follows :

```
env.fromCollection(inputRecprds).setParallelism(1)
                    .map(new TransformFunction()).setParallelism(30).print().setParallelism(30);
```